# c programming - Mandelbrot set

Tags: c, linux, opengl, mandelbrot

I am trying to display Mandelbrot set fractal using c programming, openGL, glut on linux.
Here is my code. it only displays a dot in the center. not able to figure out where I am going wrong. any help?

```
#include <GL/glut.h>    // Header File For The GLUT Library
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, count;
    float re_max=1.0, re_min=-2.0, im_max=1.0, im_min=-1.0 ; //aspect ratio 3/2
    float real_delta = (re_max - re_min)/750;
    float imag_delta = (im_max - im_min)/500;

    double complex x = 0.0 + 0.0 * I;
    double complex z = re_min + im_min * I;

    double absolute_x;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(150,150);
    glutInitWindowSize(750,500); // aspect ratio of 3/2
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);

    glClearColor (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.0);  // choosing the background color
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);      // setting the color buffer to background color
    glColor4f(0.5,0.7,0.3,0.0);
    glPointSize(1);

    for (i=0, z = re_min + im_min * I ; i<750; i++, z = (re_min + real_delta) + im_min * I)
        {

        for (j=0, z = creal(z) + im_min * I; j<500; j++, z = creal(z) + (im_min + imag_delta) * I)
            {
            count = 0;
            x = 0 + 0*I;

            while ((absolute_x = fabs(x))<=2.0 && count < 64)
            {
                x = (x * x) + z;
                count++;
            }

                if (absolute_x <= 2.0){
                    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                        glVertex2i(i,j);
                    glEnd();
                }
            }
        }

    glFlush();

    glutMainLoop();

    return (0);

}
```

Since the coding issue is solved, I am editing this question with the 'correct working code' along with a beautiful picture of the resulting fractal :-)

[image: Mandelbrot set fractal]

here is the working code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>    // Header File For The GLUT Library
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, count;
    float re_max=1., re_min=-2.0, im_max=1.0, im_min=-1.0 ; //aspect ratio 3/2
    float real_delta = (re_max - re_min)/750;
    float imag_delta = (im_max - im_min)/500;

    double complex x = 0.0 + 0.0 * I;
    double complex z = re_min + im_min * I;

    double absolute_x;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(150,150);
    glutInitWindowSize(750,500); // aspect ratio of 3/2
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);

    glClearColor (0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.0);  // choosing the background color
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);      // setting the color buffer to background color
    glColor4f(0.5,0.7,0.3,0.0);
    glPointSize(1);

    for (i=0, z = re_min + im_min * I ; i<750; i++, z = (creal(z) + real_delta) + im_min * I)
        {

        for (j=0, z = creal(z) + im_min * I; j<500; j++, z = creal(z) + (cimag(z) + imag_delta) * I)
            {
            count = 0;
            x = 0 + 0*I;

            while ((absolute_x = fabs(x))<=2.0 && count < 64)
            {
                x = (x * x) + z;
                count++;
            }

                if (absolute_x <= 2.0){
                    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                        glVertex2f(i / 750., j / 500.);;
                    glEnd();
                }
            }
        }

    glFlush();

    glutMainLoop();

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `absolute_x = cabs(x);` or `<tgmath.h>`?

Comment: `it only displays a dot in the center.` I've compiled & run your code and found your call to `glBegin` was never invoked, at least on my laptop (Linux x86_64).

Comment: Your loop seems weird: in each loop of `i` you have a same `z`, and also i think you're not getting right `z` from the loop of `j`

Comment: You are never using `i` and `j`.

Comment: If you have an error `No display callback registered for window 1` like I had, then just add `glutDisplayFunc(display);` which points to empty `display` fuction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There're two major mistakes:

1. Your loops looks weird. The loop of `i` don't change `z`'s value in each of it's iteration, and so is `j`.
   Suggestion: don't update `z` in the loop statement which would only make things complicated, instead calculate it directly in the loop body like this:

   ```
   for (i=0; i<750; i++)
   {
       for (j=0; j<500; j++)
       {
           z = re_min + real_delta * i + (im_min + imag_delta * j) * I;
           /* other of your codes */
        }
    }
   ```
2. You're not using `OpenGL` the right way. By invoking `glVertex2i(i, j);` you're specifying the coordinates `x=i` and `y=j`, but the default viewport of `OpenGL` is `(-1,1)x(-1,1)`.
   Here're two solutions you could use:

   - Placing a `glScalef` after created the window to specify the scales on coordinates and don't change other part of your code:

     ```
     /* ... */
     glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
     glScalef(1. / 750., 1. / 500., 1.);
     /* ... */
     ```
   - Passing scaled coordinates:

     ```
     /* don't use this line of your code: */
     /* glVertex2i(i, j); */
     /* while use this line: */
     glVertex2f(i / 750., j / 500.);
     ```

Comment: @Saurabh Quite a pleasure to help. :D

Comment: @Saurabh Maybe post the fractal pic?

Comment: @chux I have added now the fractal picture in the question itself :-)